# JQuery - .hover() after .load()ing the image and .append()ed to .find()div

Tags: jquery, html, image, click, hover

Hi :) I've ran into a bit of a trouble.

(short-form: whenever the page is populated by .each() the .hover and .click functions wont work. althought if i populate the the page manually .hover()s and .click()s work like a charm)

formerly i had this:

```
<imgThumb imgn="1">thumb</imgThumb>
<imgThumb imgn="2">thumb</imgThumb>
```

and this,

```
   $("imgt").hover(
 function () {
  var imgN = $(this).attr("imgn");
  var img = new Image();
  $(img).load(function(){
 $(this).hide();
 $("#mainRight_PubSpot").append(this);
 $(this).fadeIn();
  }
  )
  .attr("src","image/thumb"+imgN+".jpg");
 }, 
 function () {
   $("#mainRight_PubSpot").find("img:last").remove();
 }
```

);
worked like a charm, no biggies. Until i replaced `<imgThumb>` with this:

```
 $.get('gallery.php',
 function(data){
 var obj = jQuery.parseJSON(data); 
 //alert(obj)


 $.each(obj,function(index, value){
   //alert(this);
   var n = index+1;
   //alert(""+n+" "+index);
   var nimg = new Image();
    $(nimg).load(function() {
     $(this).hide();
     /*$("#galImg").css({
      'width':50,
      'height':50
     });*/
     $("#mainLeft_imgHold").append("<imgt imgn="+n+"></imgt>")
     $("#mainLeft_imgHold").find('imgt:last').append(this);
     $(this).fadeIn();
    }).attr({
     src:""+this,
     imgn:""+n,
     id:"imgThumb"
     });
  });
     }
 );
```

Now the images load without a sweat wahtsoever althought the .hover and .click functions wont work.

Anyone has a hint on to what might be causing all this commotion?

Comment: Can you put the code for the last part in better shape?

Comment: See the jQuery documentation on "live", (event delegation) which is just for such cases.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are loading elements after pageload (asynchronously, etc.) you need to attach handlers like `hover` and `click` with the `.live()` method.

Here's a link to the API page: http://api.jquery.com/live/

Note that `.live()` doesn't support all of jQuery's smarter listeners (like `hover`) out of the box. You may end up having to instantiate the `mouseover` and `mouseout` manually:

```
$("imgt").live('mouseover', function(){...

$("imgt").live('mouseout', function(){...
```

There are ways around this by creating your own listeners, but that's another answer for another question.

Comment: "hover" is supported in version 1.4. The documentation says: •As of jQuery 1.4.1 the hover event can be specified (mapping to mouseenter and mouseleave, which, in turn, are mapped to mouseover and mouseout).

Comment: I think i can manage pretty fly with these now and jump to "own listeners" when this hits the v1 :P Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks Neil. I knew they added some; didn't realize `hover` was one of 'em.

Answer (score 1):

The reason it fails is because when you add new items to a page with Javascript, the DOM changes and the Javascript needs to be re-rendered.

http://api.jquery.com/live/ can fix this for you, or you can try implementing your own method of checking if the DOM has changed with `.change()` handler.

Comment: That.. makes perfect sense. I wonder how it never occured to me that the DOM couldnt magically understand that there was new stuff.

Thanks :)